# Convert as fastest as possible integer n between two bases - built-in function

Tags: c++, algorithm, converters, radix

I have an integer in one base (base != 10 && 1 < base < 17) inputted from standard input to string. I have to convert it to other one in the same range (1 < base < 17). Cause really restriced time limits my program has to do that as fast as that is only possible. Is there any built-in function to do that? I tried to look in STL, but I didn't find any.

I have written my own function to convert integer n from base from range 1-10 to base 10 and from this base to other base in range 1-10, but I am unable to do that for bases > 10 (like e.g. 11 or 16).

My current code:

```
int wynik = 0;
string wynikowy="";

int potega(int liczba, int stp)
{
int wynik = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < stp; i++)
{
wynik = wynik * liczba;
}
return wynik;
}

void zamien(string s, int system)
{
for(int i = s.length()-1; i >=0 ; i --)
{
wynik=wynik+(int)(s.at(i)-'0')*potega(system,s.length()-1-i);
}
}

void zamienNa(int liczba, int system)
{
stringstream ss;
if(liczba < system)
{
ss << liczba;
wynikowy+=ss.str();
}
else
{
ss << liczba%system;
wynikowy+=ss.str();
zamienNa((liczba-liczba%system)/system, system);
}
}
```

Use example:

```
zamien(s,4); //from base
zamienNa(wynik,5); // to base
for(int i = wynikowy.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
cout << wynikowy.at(i);
}
```

Comment: _'I have written my own function to convert ...'_ Too shy to show us what you have, may be that could give some useful pointers how to fix your actual problems??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Simply, letters like "A" or "D" are totally breaking working of my function

Comment: @Ty221 There are [standard I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase) implementations for bases of 8,10 and 16. May be looking at their implementation, might help for doing your own. Though as long you don't show what you have, we're not able to point out how to fix it!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I one case I have to change n from base 11 to base 14. How can I do that by standard I/O manipulators

Comment: A hint: If you're reading letters instead of characters from `'0'` to `'9'` the digit value these are representing can be calculated by `unsigned int digitValue = digitChar - 'A';`, supposed `digitChar` is the current `char` read and normalized to upper-case.

Comment: Assuming this is ASCII-based.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you.  I will implement that. I repeat my question - is there built-in function? I have got timeline to send this project in 1,5 hour I do not know will I be able to finish it

Comment: @Ty221 No, there's no simple build in function, at least not I know of :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ :( So can you give me an example of how does that function  should look like? I am not fluent in C++ and I have really short timeline...

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast No, it doesn't matter if it's ASCII based or not (note I have used `digitChar - 'A'`), it will work for EBCDIC or whatever the actual compiler uses to implement for numerical representation of a `char` literal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I guess I assumed you were on track to getting 10 for `'A'` etc.

Comment: @Ty221 Additional hint: Dieter Lücking's comment leads to the [available standard function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) (without limitation for bases to 8,10 and 16)

Comment: Fastest way is probably inline assembler.

Comment: @ThomasW. I mean fastest way in C++

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that “that” refers to the title, ”Convert as fastest as possible integer n between two bases”, then

re

> **”** Is there any built-in function to do that?

The `strtol` function converts from string to `long` with a specified base ≤ 36. There is however no built-in or standard library function to convert *to* string of arbitrary base. Happily that’s easy to implement.

And re

> **”**  I am unable to do that for bases > 10.

There's no difference except the representation of digits. Think about converting between displayable ASCII character, and *digit value*. I can't really say more without spoonfeeding you a solution, but hopefully that's enough of a hint.